# Error when deploying EAR in wildfly

Tags: jboss, jenkins, ear, wildfly

```
 Tue Apr 01 17:41:45 GMT+200 2014
Failed to enable fal2-ear-0.0.8.ear.

Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "address" => [("deployment" => "fal2-ear-0.0.8.ear")],
    "operation" => "deploy"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
        "Services that were unable to start:" => [
            "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"fal2-ear-0.0.8.ear\".\"ccbe-fal2.war\".INSTALL",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"fal2-ear-0.0.8.ear\".INSTALL"
        ],
        "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"]
    }},
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

I always get this error when I want to deploy my Multi module maven Spring project in wildfly.
Jenkins made an EAR file for me and i Just added it to wildfly.

Anyone knows what it means? I can't find it on the internet

Thx !!

My error log file:

```
    2014-04-01 09:21:08,942 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "fal2-ear-0.0.6.ear" (runtime-name: "fal2-ear-0.0.6.ear")
2014-04-01 09:21:09,425 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "null" (runtime-name: "ccbe-fal2.war")
2014-04-01 09:21:11,599 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (XNIO-1 task-6) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "fal2-ear-0.0.6.ear")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => [
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"fal2-ear-0.0.6.ear\".\"ccbe-fal2.war\".INSTALL",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"fal2-ear-0.0.6.ear\".INSTALL"
    ],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"]
}}
2014-04-01 09:21:11,614 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (XNIO-1 task-6) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "fal2-ear-0.0.6.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => [
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"fal2-ear-0.0.6.ear\".\"ccbe-fal2.war\".INSTALL",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"fal2-ear-0.0.6.ear\".INSTALL"
    ],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"]
}}
2014-04-01 09:21:11,692 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: ccbe-fal2.war) in 79ms
2014-04-01 09:21:11,692 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment fal2-ear-0.0.6.ear (runtime-name: fal2-ear-0.0.6.ear) in 83ms
2014-04-01 09:21:11,692 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (XNIO-1 task-6) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.listener.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.listener.default: Could not start http listener
```

Comment: what does your server.log say?

Comment: stupid. the port 8080 was already in use :)

Answer (score 11):

Actually I had the same problem for a standalone Wildfly.

1. First I took a look at standalone/log/server.log. Last lines said
   http listener didn't initialize.
2. Then I checked standalone/configuration/standalone-full.xml. It said
   that http had  8080 assigned.
3. Checked the ports and 8080 was in use by cherokee    server.

So I changed the cherokee port and restarted both (Cherokee and Wildfly) servers and that did the trick.

Hope you solved the problem as I did it.

Comment: @Rodrigo: This error could also be caused if one adds multiple http listeners.